# setcontview(R.layout.blah) - can i define 'blah' on the fly?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hopefully this is easy to do, I've tried searching for it with no luck, my apologies if it was previously answered.

I want to be able to build 'blah' in setcontentview(R.layout.blah) as shown below in my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.options_sounds);
```

Where options_sounds will be defined by a user selected spinner.  I'd like to save it as a string and then read it into the setcontentview line somehow.   All the blah.xml files will have been previously built and ready to go, I just want the user to tell me which one he/she wants.

Thank you for your time.
-c

Answer (score 0):

You could use a switch statement and load the user's selection, since the layouts are already built and "ready to go".

```
switch(layout_selection) {
        case 1:
                    setContentView(R.layout.layout1);
            break;
        case 2:
                    setContentView(R.layout.layout2);
            break;
}
```

Comment: I like it!  simple but effective.  Thx for the suggestion.

Comment: @Chris please mark this as the answer, if it does indeed answer your question. Thanks.